# Changing value of an input date picker with button angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui, angularjs-model

I have have an input field which is attached an Angular UI datepicker.
Below that, I added 2 buttons to change date, "day by day".

Here is the input part (just after in my page):

```
<p class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon hidden-xs">From</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="parent.dtFrom"   ng-change="refresh(0)" show-button-bar="false" is-open="opened1" max-date="maxDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" readonly />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event, 'opened1')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
    </span>
</p>
```

And here are my button to change it:

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 btn-group" role="group" >
   <div class="text-center" >
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-outline glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left text-center previousdate" ng-click="addDayFrom(-1)"></button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-outline glyphicon glyphicon-home text-center todaydate"  ng-click="DateFromToday()"></button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-outline glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right text-center nextdate" ng-click="addDayFrom(1)" ng-show="parent.dtFrom < todate" ></button>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Here is how I init my `dtFrom` at the begin of my controller:

```
$scope.parent={
    dtFrom : new Date(),
    dtTo : new Date()
};
```

And this is my function for change `dtFrom`:

```
$scope.addDayFrom=function(day){
    $scope.parent.dtFrom.setDate($scope.parent.dtFrom.getDate() +  parseInt(day));
    console.log($scope.parent.dtFrom);
};
```

It change value in `$scope.parent.dtFrom` but **model isn't updated into input.**

Example: Today we are `12/05/2015`.

If I click one time on previous button, `$scope.parent.dtFrom` will be `11/05/2015`.

And that's what is displayed all **but the input.**

I suppose that's a scope issue, but can't figure out where it is.
Have you any clue to fix this ?

***Edit:*** Picture here : http://hpics.li/4e0fab6

Comment: Try printing `{{parent.dtFrom}}` before the input and see if the value is changing as you expect.

Comment: It changes, that's why i don't get where is the problem

Comment: Is it calling `refresh(0)`?

Comment: Nope, I guess it should. Then it implies that Angular didn't caught the change $scope.parent.dtFrom ?
Should I add a  $watch ?

Comment: I found a solution but it's more hack than Angular way's.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Change your code from:

```
$scope.addDayFrom=function(day){
    $scope.parent.dtFrom.setDate($scope.parent.dtFrom.getDate() +  parseInt(day));
    console.log($scope.parent.dtFrom);
};
```

To this:

```
$scope.addDayFrom=function(day){
    $scope.parent.dtFrom = ($scope.parent.dtFrom.getDate() +  parseInt(day));
    console.log($scope.parent.dtFrom);
};
```

---

Looking at the [Angular UI datepicker documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker), you can see that you don't need to access `parent`. I thought you were trying to access the `parent` scope, but actually you were accessing the `parent` attribute that you have set here:

```
$scope.parent={
    dtFrom : new Date(),
    dtTo : new Date()
};
```

Angular UI datepicker is watching by reference, as we can see in [their source code](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/datepicker/datepicker.js), what makes perfect sense, since that's the most efficient watching strategy. To understand more about that, read [Scope `$watch` Depths](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-watch-depths) on Angular core documentation:

> #### [Scope `$watch` Depths](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-watch-depths)
>
> Dirty checking can be done with three strategies: By reference, by
>   collection contents, and by value. The strategies differ in the kinds
>   of changes they detect, and in their performance characteristics.
>
> - Watching *by reference* ([`scope.$watch (watchExpression, listener)`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)) detects a change when the whole value returned by the
>     watch expression switches to a new value. If the value is an array or
>     an object, changes inside it are not detected. This is the most
>     efficient strategy.
> - Watching *collection contents* ([`scope.$watchCollection (watchExpression, listener)`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchCollection)) detects changes that occur inside an
>     array or an object: When items are added, removed, or reordered. The
>     detection is shallow - it does not reach into nested collections.
>     Watching collection contents is more expensive than watching by
>     reference, because copies of the collection contents need to be
>     maintained. However, the strategy attempts to minimize the amount of
>     copying required.
> - Watching *by value* ([`scope.$watch (watchExpression, listener, true)`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)) detects any change in an arbitrarily nested data
>     structure. It is the most powerful change detection strategy, but also
>     the most expensive. A full traversal of the nested data structure is
>     needed on each digest, and a full copy of it needs to be held in
>     memory.
>
>   [image]

That's why it wasn't detecting `$scope.parent.dtFrom.setDate(newDate)` usage, and the model wasn't being updated. So, just change that piece of code to `$scope.parent.dtFrom = newDate`, and it should work (as it has already worked with your global variable approach).

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of hack but, it works ... so I share it with you

When i start my app i create a  local date variable that i change when i click on my button. when it's done, i do that :

```
$scope.parent.dtFrom = new Date(localDateVariable);
```

Not the best solution, but a solution.

Comment: Maybe `$scope.parent.dtFrom.setDate($scope.parent.dtFrom.getDate() +  parseInt(day));` isn't correct. How do you set `locaDateVariable`?

Comment: When app start, I init `$scope.parent.dtFrom` and my `localDateVariable` as date object.
Then, on click event on previous day button, i fire a function which  remove one day to `localDateVariable` with `localDateVariable.setDate(localDateVariable.getDate() + parseInt(day));`, Then i just assign it to `$scope.parent.dtFrom = new Date(localDateVariable);`

For keeping updated my local variable, when i catch change event from datepicker on my input, I do that : `localDateVariable = $scope.parent.dtFrom;`